# Como criar elementos de um typehead em uma div a parte

Tags: javascript, html, plugin, typeahead

Estou precisando desenvolver um input que retorna informações do banco de dados, porem essas informações tem que estar visível em uma div no lado direito da pagina

ja tentei um monte de coisa, mas não consegui nada.

Minha página de testes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>

    </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <br>

        <input id='#typeahead' type='text'>
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <ul id="typeahead-target"></ul>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/typeahead.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#typeahead').typeahead({menu: '#typeahead-target'});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Alguem sabe como ?

Answer (score 2):

Segue um exemplo de como fazer o que você precisa:

```js
$(function () {

  v1 = $("#elemento").val();

  $('#elemento').keyup(function() {
      
      v1 = $("#elemento").val();
      $('#texto').append("<p>"+v1+"</p>");
      $("#texto").show();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type='text' id='elemento' name='elemento' value=''>


<div id="texto" style='height: 200px; background-color: blue; margin-top: 20px; display: none;'></div>
```

Comment: serve! isso que eu queria, só preciso adaptar